# Editing ClearDB password in VCAP_SERVICES environment variable in Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, dashboard, cleardb

I reset the password to my `ClearDB` database from the [dashboard](https://www.cleardb.com/dashboard) and can't seem to find a way to update the new password in Bluemix's `VCAP_SERVICES` environment variable, especially with the new console. I could create a custom environment variable but that would force me to edit the code - doesn't seem like a good solution.

Is there a way to do that, short of nuking the db, creating a new one and restoring the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unbind the ClearDB service from the Bluemix application that is using it and then bind it again. `VCAP_SERVICES` will be updated with new ClearDB password.

Comment: It is documented in the Cloud Foundry documentation (Bluemix is based off the Cloud Foundry open source). See "Update Service Credentials" session in this link:  https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/services/application-binding.html